# ISNULL with aggregate function

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

What is the best way to go about using these two together? In my case if a userID is `null` I want to return zero, and users can have multiple ID's so we want to have get the lowest (the original) one.

```
ISNULL(MIN(UserId),0)
```

Or,

```
MIN(ISNULL(UserId),0)
```

Thank you.

Is the answer indicative of all aggregate functions?

Comment: The answer is obvious if you think about what you want to do and how the parser will evaluate each option.

Comment: Second one will cause syntax error. It should be `MIN(ISNULL(UserId,0))`

Comment: Please tag your question with your DBMS (Sql Server, Oracle...)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do.  But I am biased towards `COALESCE()` because it is the ANSI standard function.

Your two options are:

```
COALESCE(MIN(UserId), 0)
MIN(COALESCE(UserId, 0))
```

These do not do the same thing.  The first returns the minimum user id.  If *all* user ids are `NULL`, then this expression returns `0`.

The second replaces each `NULL` with `0`.  Assuming the user ids are positive, then this returns `0` if *any* user ids are `NULL`.

Based on my understanding of your logic, you want the second version.

Answer (score 3):

Those statements do not necessarily produce the same output:

- the first takes the minimum that exists and only if that is null, uses 0.
- the second checks each user id and if that is null uses 0 - it then takes the minimum of those (and unless a user ID can be negative, a user with a 5 and a null, would output 0)

A quick script can demonstrate this :

```
with testData as (
  select 1 as SomeKey, 5 as userID
  union all 
  select 1 as SomeKey, null as userID
  union all
  select 2 as SomeKey, 6 as userID
  union all 
  select 2 as SomeKey, 5 as userID
)
select
  somekey
  , isnull(min(userid),0) as firstScenario
  , min(isnull(userid,0)) as SecondScenario
from testdata
group by somekey
```

Results:

```
Somekey    firstScenario    secondScenario
1          5                0
2          5                5
```

The first scenario is the most likely one you were after, but the phrasing of the question makes it a bit ambiguous as to what the desired behaviour was.

(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/10170)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use `SQL Server`, bacause ISNULL is a `T-Sql` function.

To use a function accross DBMS you can use `COALESCE`

`NULL` values are not included in MIN functions.

So If you want to prevent NULL result, I advice you to use the first solution

```
ISNULL(MIN(UserId), 0)
```